# Tau2Slog2 not able to process 6gb tau.trc files

Tags: mpi, hpc, mpich

I am profiling my code using the TAU profiler. I am using `tau_exec` at runtime.  It generates trace files. Some of which are in gigabytes. `tau_treemerge.pl` merges and generates a `tau.trc` which is 6GB. `tau2slog2` now fails complaining about the heap space.

It would be helpful if anybody can show how to reduce the size of trace files.

Following is the way I am running the code:

```
mpirun -n  64 tau_exec ./a.out 
tau_treemerge.pl;
tau2slog2 tau.tr tau.edf -o tau.slog2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by increasing the heap size of the JVM.

```
java -Xmx50000m -Xms32000m -cp /tau/x86_64/lib/TAU_tf.jar:/tau/x86_64/lib/traceTOslog2.jar:/tau/x86_64/lib/tau2slog2.jar edu/uoregon/tau/Tau2Slog2  tau.trc tau.edf -o tau.slog2
```

Obviously it is a workaround and not an elegant solution. So to reduce the tau.trc filesize I have added more filtering parameters during the instrumentation.

Also I first just profiled the code `export TAU_PROFILE=1` and then ran pprof and figured out which MPI function is called enormously then throttled those functions to further reduce the file size.